# iOS: Manual Retain Release on iOS development

Tags: ios

I am working with the project where i am doing manual retain and release. I have come across one of many tutorials related to this on the following link.

http://www.drdobbs.com/mobile/automatic-reference-counting-on-ios/240000820

I am little confused from the above link. Under 'Managing by Messaging' title, they mentioned if i use 'alloc/init' it increases the ref. count to '1', if I again 'retain' it, it again increases and becomes '2' and again use 'retain', becomes now '3', but they are **NOT** 'releasing' three times to completely free this memory, instead they are freeing only two times. How this is possible? I'm little confused after seeing this.

Comment: maybe vdots indicate additional `release`s? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not only releasing two times, they're just showing that they're releasing until the retainCount is 0, which is correct.

Comment: oh got it! So, if the count increases to '3' as mentioned above, we must to have 'release' 3 times right to freeing it completely?

Comment: Yes that would be correct. If you retain three times, you must release three times, that would decrement its retain count to 0 releasing it for good! (If my knowledge is correct)

Comment: No, I'm not retaining 3 times. I am retaining only two times, but prior to that alloc/init once, so total ref. count is '3', this is what i have said. So, in this case also as i mentioned in my question ref. count becomes '3', i have to 'release' it '3' times right at the appropriate places?

Comment: Objects start of with a retainCount of 1. Say you retain it, babam, it has a retainCount of 2. Now lets say you release it, babam it becomes a retainCount of 1. But that object is still there, it is not fully released, you need to release it again.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion I changed my name to 'TeenDev' if you would like to reply

Comment: Hi, Here is my sample. i) alloc/init - count is '1' ; (ii) 'retain' once - count is '2' ; (iii) 'retain' one more time - count is '3' . In this scenario, i need to 'release' this object three times at the appropriate places, Is this right or wrong?

Comment: @TeenDev That is correct. All objects start with a retainCount of 1 when created. You can use something called a `convenience method`, for example: `[NSMutableArray array]`, which simply does `[[[NSMutableArray] alloc] init] autorelease]`.

Comment: @SimonGermain exactly, that kind of method returns an autoreleased object by hand, which means that even though it has a retain count of 1, it will automatically release upon dismissal of the view controller or deallocation or whatever.

Comment: It'll release upon a call to the `drain` method on the `NSAutoreleasePool`.